# Why can I only have one ProxyPass'ed subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.4, dnsmasq

Edit: The problem disappeared when I restarted my computer. I apologize for wasting everyone's time with this!

---

I'm trying to set up local .dev domains for my different production apps. I have an entry like this in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost app.appname.dev:80>
   ServerName app.appname.dev
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost ppa.appname.dev:80>
   ServerName ppa.appname.dev
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using dnsmasq to route traffic from *.dev to localhost (using `address=/dev/127.0.0.1` in my dnsmasq.conf)

Okay, the mystery is that `app.appname.example` works perfectly fine. But `ppa.appname.dev` gives an this error message in my browser:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service
>      your request due to maintenance downtime or
>      capacity problems. Please try again later.

I've restarted apache many times, flushed my dns, tried different orderings of these VirtualHost declarations, and nothing seems to jiggle it loose. Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up, @Hyppy! You made this look much nicer.

Comment: In the past, I always found apache reverse proxying to not work properly.  However, when using nginx or haproxy it seemed to just work so simply.  Try those.

Comment: I use Apache reverse proxying every day on a large site without complaint. I would suggest that you post the output of `getent hosts app.appname.dev`. This will show you the same result that Apache would get when it does a lookup on the name (it takes into account things like /etc/hosts and other potential caching layers such as nscd).

Comment: Other than using dnsmasqd, if you only want this on your local machine, just add the following line in /etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 ppa.appname.dev`.

Comment: Do you have the command `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your config?

Comment: Why are both VHOSTs proxying to same exact backend? It makes this configuration unnecessarily redundant. Are you getting warning messages on your apache logs about duplicated proxy stanzas?

Comment: @CameronKerr: I'm on osx, so no getent, but I used `dscacheutil`, and both subdomains have the address 127.0.0.1. I am trying to set up a local wildcard subdomain, so the hosts file unfortunately isn't enough. I added `NameVirtualHost *:80`, and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @dawud: I have them identical (except for `app` vs `ppa`) because I'm troubleshooting. Once I get this working I'll be adding plenty of extra functionality. :)

Comment: Okay, this is strange. I've commented out both of these `VirtualHost`s, and app.appname.dev is still resolving. This makes me think there is config somewhere that is not getting refreshed. I'm editing the `httpd.conf` I get from running `apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`, and restarting apache each time. :/